# dnsmasq does not resolve directly specified name

Tags: dnsmasq

I have trouble with **dnsmasq** - it does not resolve directly defined name.

```
$ sudo dnsmasq -d -A /test/172.17.0.2 --log-queries &
dnsmasq: started, version 2.48 cachesize 150
dnsmasq: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-I18N DHCP TFTP "--bind-interfaces with SO_BINDTODEVICE"
dnsmasq: read /etc/hosts - 2 addresses

$ ping test
ping: unknown host test
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You only set up a server. Your system's resolver (which is used by ping, your browser, and all other applications on your machine) must first know that this server exists and that it should be used. This can be done by modifying `/etc/resolv.conf`. For first, make sure, this line is in that file:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

But beware: modern systems auto-generate this file and potentially overwrite your changes. So watch out for "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND" comments in that file and instead do what's recommended in the file.